# Will using Byte as a data type for intent request code has any advantage over Integer?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

When navigating from one activity to another and get result back we use request codes which are usually defined as a constant. e.g. REQUEST_CODE_GROUP = 1.

Considering we don't use a lot of request code in our application should we store them in a byte instead of integer.

Comment: For flags int is common practice but doesnt make a difference its just a convetion. Perhaps use an enum http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/enums.html#:~:text=A%20Java%20Enum%20is%20a,were%20added%20in%20Java%205.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed store your request codes in shorter data format like byte or char. It is technically more optimized. Now, *should you?*
You are specifying that you're not using a lot of them. So the memory you'll gain from this will probably not be worth the typecasting you'll need to do. Consider whether you *need* this optimisation.

Comment: It would only be more “optimized” (in terms of memory use) if multiple flags were packed together into an array or larger primitive.

Answer (score 0):

Request codes have to be integers as that's what the sdk expects - e.g. `void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data)` and `startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode)`. So you can't pass in bytes instead, at least without converting them.